# Does the order matter in ORDER BY clause?

Tags: mysql, sql

in the **`SQL`** `ORDER BY` clause, For a table like this in example.

```
[ a  -  b   -   c   -  d ]
--------------------------
[ x  -  1   -   i   -  e ]
[ y  -  2   -   k   -  f ]
[ z  -  3   -   m   -  g ]
```

If i wrote the clause like the following

```
ORDER BY a ASC, b DESC, c DESC, d ASC
```

Is there any difference if i changed the order of the columns to somehting like

```
ORDER BY d DESC, c DESC, b ASC, a ASC
```

Or does it work the same and doesn't make any difference since it will always pick the exact `ORDER` for columns where `d DESC, c DESC, b ASC, a ASC` which is the same as `ORDER BY a ASC, b DESC, c DESC, d ASC` but in difference order?

Comment: Poor sample data...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ORDER BY a ASC, b DESC, c DESC, d ASC` means that

- First Order a in Ascending order
- Then order b in descending order
- Then order c in descending order
- At last order d in Ascending order

In your example it does not matter because values are the same but in below example it senses such as

Example Inordered list suach as;

```
| a  |  b  |  c  | d  |
-----------------------
| 10 |  5  |  2  |  7 | 
| 10 |  3  |  1  |  7 | 
| 5  |  5  |  6  |  3 | 
| 4  |  2  |  5  |  3 | 
| 5  |  4  |  6  |  3 |    
| 3  |  5  |  9  |  4 |
| 3  |  6  |  6  |  4 | 
| 5  |  5  |  6  |  3 | 
| 4  |  2  |  5  |  3 | 
| 5  |  4  |  6  |  3 |    
| 3  |  5  |  1  |  4 |
| 3  |  6  |  2  |  4 |
```

and `ORDER BY d ASC, a ASC, b DESC, c DESC;`

```
 | a   |  b |  c | d  |
 -----------------------
 |  4  |  2 |  5 |  3 |
 |  4  |  2 |  5 |  3 |
 |  5  |  5 |  6 |  3 |
 |  5  |  5 |  6 |  3 |
 |  5  |  4 |  6 |  3 |
 |  5  |  4 |  6 |  3 |
 |  3  |  6 |  6 |  4 |
 |  3  |  6 |  2 |  4 |
 |  3  |  5 |  9 |  4 |
 |  3  |  5 |  1 |  4 |
 |  10 |  5 |  2 |  7 |
 |  10 |  3 |  1 |  7 |
```

then Ordered by after `ORDER BY a ASC, b DESC, c DESC, d ASC` is

```
 | a  |  b |  c |  d | 
  --------------------
 | 3  |  6 |  6 |  4 | 
 | 3  |  6 |  6 |  4 | 
 | 3  |  6 |  2 |  4 | 
 | 3  |  5 |  9 |  4 | 
 | 3  |  5 |  1 |  4 | 
 | 4  |  2 |  5 |  3 | 
 | 4  |  2 |  5 |  3 | 
 | 5  |  5 |  6 |  3 | 
 | 5  |  5 |  6 |  3 | 
 | 5  |  4 |  6 |  3 | 
 | 5  |  4 |  6 |  3 | 
 | 10 |  5 |  2 |  7 | 
 | 10 |  3 |  1 |  7 |
```

For `ORDER BY d DESC, c DESC, b ASC, a ASC` , result will be like that

```
 |  a  |  b |  c |  d | 
 |  10 |  5 |  2 |  7 |
 |  10 |  3 |  1 |  7 |
 |  3  |  5 |  9 |  4 |
 |  3  |  6 |  6 |  4 |
 |  3  |  6 |  2 |  4 |
 |  3  |  5 |  1 |  4 |
 |  5  |  4 |  6 |  3 |
 |  5  |  4 |  6 |  3 |
 |  5  |  5 |  6 |  3 |
 |  5  |  5 |  6 |  3 |
 |  4  |  2 |  5 |  3 |
 |  4  |  2 |  5 |  3 |
```

Please play the given example with order commands here http://rextester.com/LKBRK29917

Answer (score 3):

The two are very, very different.

`ASC` and `DESC` apply to a specific key.  It is not related to the order of the keys.

So, the first `ORDER BY` orders by column `a` in ascending order.  The rest of the keys are only used when there are ties `a`.

The second `ORDER BY` orders by column `d` in descending order.  The rest of the keys are only used when there are ties in `d`.

Of course, you could find specific data where the two versions are the same.  But that would be highly unusual.

Answer (score 2):

The order of columns/expressions showing up does matter.  It orders by the first one as specified, then orders that set by the next one, then by the next.  The result is different than if you were to reverse the order in which the columns are ordered.

Think of each ordered column as a sub-order of the previous ordered column.

(really, you could have tested this in less time than it took to write the question...)